# How to represent an edge with the weight zero in an adjacency matrix

Tags: graph-theory

How can I differentiate in an adjacency matrix between an existing edge that has weight zero and a non-existing edge between two nodes?

I learned that if two edges are not adjacent, the value in the matrix should be zero, but I have a graph example that shows a weight between two nodes equal to zero. What should I do?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to do with that adjacency matrix.  Different algorithms require different approaches to your question.  So, what are you doing with that adjacency matrix?

Comment: I just started learning Graph and this became confusing. If I create a graph using an adjacency matrix that has an edge with value 0 how to proceed?